# How to delete a group of rows in R dplyr if there is one deletion flag in only one row for this group?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

My code works but it is very slow when the data frame is big.
Is there any more efficient way of doing this.

```
library(dplyr)

df = data.frame(
  group = c(1,1, 2,2),
  delete_flag = c('','X','','')
)

df_2 <- df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  do({
    if('X' %in% .$delete_flag) {data.frame(NULL)} else {.}
  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `filter()` instead.

```r
df %>%
  filter(!'X' %in% delete_flag, .by = group)

# # A tibble: 2 × 2
#   group delete_flag
#   <dbl> <chr>
# 1     2 ""
# 2     2 ""
```

---

Version before `dplyr v1.1.0`:

```r
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  filter(!'X' %in% delete_flag) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of groups it might be more performant to just filter based on a mask below named `delete_grp`. This avoids filter for each group.

```r
library(dplyr)

delete_grp <- unique(df$group[df$delete_flag == "X"])

df %>% 
  filter(!group %in% delete_grp)
#>   group delete_flag
#> 1     2            
#> 2     2
```

Data from OP

```r
df = data.frame(
  group = c(1,1, 2,2),
  delete_flag = c('','X','','')
)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>